Java (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection() return 403 for some valid URL
I need to read HTML as test or stream from first web site page like pubs.acs.org, I have the code below that works for many URLs but for some of them it returns 403 error, I test this URLs in browser and all of them is available and valid.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        // URL to connect to
        String urlString = "https://pubs.acs.org";
        
        // Open connection
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        
        // Set request properties
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Origin", "https://pubs.acs.org");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Host", "pubs.acs.org");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Referer", "https://pubs.acs.org");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "cookie_name=cookie_value"); // Add actual cookies if needed

        // Set timeouts
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

        // Check if the connection is an instance of HttpURLConnection and set request method to GET
        if (urlConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

        // Open the connection
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Read the response
        try (InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Print the result
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}

I use Jsoup like below but 403 error return again.
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://pubs.acs.org";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")
                .referrer("https://pubs.acs.org")
                .get();

        System.out.println(doc.html());
    }
}

server response is some think like below with other type of code:

Server:cloudflare Date:Mon, 10 Jun 2024 14:05:25 GMT
Content-Type:text/html Content-Length:553 Connection:keep-alive
CF-RAY:8919ea8cda2e18da-FRA 403 Forbidden  403
Forbidden  403
Forbidden cloudflare 

Can every one correct my code or give me any other 100% working approach ?

The number of sites that would respond to that sort of 'early web' type of client is probably vanishingly small these days. Mostly, scripting support is essential as is cookie management

The web page you are trying to access requires authentication as evident by the 403 HTTP status response you are receiving. It is up to you to understand and implement the right type of authentication needed by the site, for the HTTP client that you may be using.
For example if the site requires HTTP Basic authentication and you are using HttpURLConnection see this answer: Connecting to remote URL which requires authentication using Java.

But of course a browser connects perfectly well to https://pubs.acs.org/ without auth

How can I find what kind of authentication it needs? Is it possible that it needs to solve a captcha or something to detects request is not from robots?

@g00se I don't think it is an (on-topic question)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic] for [so] to ask about resolving authentication for a specific site at a given point in time. That could change at any moment without notice making the answer invalid and it is more related to third party services. What would be on-topic for me is to ask about a specific authentication method.

@MrSalesi you could ask them or debug the HTTP traffic/HTML/JavaScript of the page to understand what it does. In the browser works, but when I tried it directed me to a verification page. You need to understand how to reproduce that behavior.

@aled many sites and URLs has not this feature, It is a sample for test with other user, you must understand the difference.

How can I find what kind of authentication it needs? It doesn't need any (for a basic response). Didn't you try it in your browser? It would be quite strange for a public site to have its public-facing main page requiring auth. It would make no sense

I just opened the page in the browser. First time there was some kind of check, like some Cloudflare browser checks. You can try it in Curl: curl -v --http1.1 https://pubs.acs.org. Response status is HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden. There is some magic there from the cloud provider that may not be easy to replicate. Doesn't seem to be a cookie so I guess it is fully server side.

@MrSalesi apparently the site is trying actively to prevent non human access. If you are trying to bypass that you'll probably need a client that can understand how to avoid that fingerprinting. Recommending libraries is off topic here. There are other questions in the site regarding that scenario. Try searching for those.
